# Solving the differential equation $G'(x)=G(x)G'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, limits, derivatives

Can someone please help me find $G(x)$ in $G'(x)=G(x)G'(0)$. My idea is to use the definition of the derivative of $G(x)$. However, I'm not sure. I wrote it out, and did not end up with the same thing.

Comment: wouldn't be $G''(x)=G'(x)G'(0)$?

Comment: Are you looking to solve this as a differential equation for G(x)?

Comment: @HHuang correct

Comment: @janmarqz thats not what the book says. I am reading it off of a mathematics finance text

Comment: @brucemcmc: then instead of wording "derive" use "solve"

Comment: Oh yes, thank you for that @janmarqz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$G'(x)=G(x)G'(0)$$
Is a first order separable differential equation:
$$\dfrac {G'(x)}{G(x)}=G'(0)$$
$$(\ln G(x))'=G'(0)$$
Integration gives us:
$$\ln G(x)=G'(0)x+C$$
$$G(x)=Ke^{G'(0)x}$$

---

You also have that
$$G'(x)=G(x)G'(0)$$
$$G'(0)=G(0)G'(0)$$
$$\implies G'(0)(1-G(0))=0$$
$$G'(0)=0 \text { or } G(0)=1$$
For $G'(0)=0 \implies G(x)=K$

For $G(0)=1 \implies G(x)=e^{G'(0)x}$

Comment: You can go further to conclude that $K=1$ or that (trivially) $G(x)$ is a constant function.

Comment: I didn't finish postting. I added some lines. Is it what you meant ? @Deepak

Comment: Yes (that's what I meant).

Comment: Oh thank you @Deepak

Comment: Alternatively, you can just differentiate your solution and set $x=0$. Quicker.

Comment: Yes you're right @Deepak

Comment: Thank you, Aryadeva.

Comment: You're welcome @brucemcmc

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this as an ODE. For clarity, take $k = G'(0)$.

Obtain the exponential solution $G(x) = Ce^{kx}$

Then differentiate the solution $G'(x) = kCe^{kx}$

Plug in initial condition $G'(0) = kC = k$, so $C = 1$.

So without detailed value of $G'(0)$, the general solution is $G(x) = e^{G'(0)x}$

Comment: Any constant function is also a solution, so this is not quite the most general. (A constant solution, rather than an exponential solution, results when $k=0$.)

Comment: Thank you, Draditate.